# How to get displayed element in div at javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get displayed element in div at javascript?. 
I have a div element on my page. There are 4 img objects in Div element. I made a slider by sliding these pictures up from below. How do I get the img object shown in that div inside?

Comment: Show me, what you have done so far!

Comment: document.getElementById("divid").getElementsByTagName("img")

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can set an id on yours images and create a var active_img in javascript

When the user use the slide you need to call a function who change the active_img var like

```
active_img=active_img+1;
```

And to get the active image you can do this :

`Var obj=document.getElementById("img_id");`

This will work but i think there is also an another way to do that you want.